# Wordpress Some Content in header file not outputting

Tags: wordpress

I'm developping a Wordpress website, and I need to display conditionnal content in header file, just after opening body tag.

If I call exit(); just after my condition, the code is outputted correctly, so I know condition is working and I'm in the right file. Then I remove the call to exit(); and code is not outputted.

Theme is Divi / Divi-Child, I removed all plugins to be sure (renamed the plugins folder to _plugins), no cache in effect.

I looked at both functions.php and child/functions.php, I don't see any 'after content' functions that would clean/remove the code, although I suspect this is what's happening.

Even the HTML comments are striped ()

```
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>



<!-- Advertising -->
    <?php
        $bool = is_sidebar_active('wallpaper-advertising');
        //var_dump($bool);
        if($bool){
        //exit();
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                if(jQuery('#ad_habillage').length>0){
                    jQuery('#adbg, .wallpaper_spacer').show(0);
                }else{
                    jQuery('body').addClass('deactivate_wallpaper');
                }
            });
        </script>
        <div id="adbg">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('wallpaper-advertising'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="wallpaper_spacer" style="">
            <img src="<?= THEME_PATH ?>/media/img/994x112Transparent.gif" border="0" alt="Cliquez ici" title="Cliquez ici">
        </div>
        <div class="big_wallpaper_wrap_bg">
        <div class="big_wallpaper_wrap">
    <?php } ?>
<!-- End Advertising -->
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that this PHP generates, and let us know what content you want to show but is not getting displayed? It's difficult to know what's happening without seeing the problem :)

Comment: Sure, here you go. https://freeimage.host/i/dwGP9V
https://freeimage.host/i/dwGiAB In black, source code with Red band to show what I expect. In white, the real output/view-source, there is no Advertising content anywhere.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code itself - images of code are against the guidelines because they are not helpful and we cannot use them to try recreating the problem. Take a look at how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can reproduce the problem and be able to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten well the code in the screenshots is the same as above in the question. I just identified clearly what was not displayed on frontend. I found out using QueryMonitor, it shows templates in use, and header.php was replaced by another file in the theme folder. I moved my code there and it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out using QueryMonitor, it shows templates in use, and header.php was replaced by another file in the theme folder. I moved my code there and it's all fine.